# Change font color on all other divs when hover one div

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to highlight one div on hover through changing the font color on all other divs (/rows).

In this example I would want all other divs with class name "b" to change font color when hovering a specific "b".

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n17a8po/2/)

```css
.a {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.b {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
}

.b:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>five</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>six</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>un</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>deux</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>trois</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>quatre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>cinq</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>six</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a shared parent, on your example, `.a` being the topmost parent is repeated so add one `<div>` that wraps everything (or use one that is already there).
Then you need to add a `:hover` on the wrapper then add a conditional `:not(:hover)` to the `.b` and then you can continue the chain or style as you want.

```css
.a {
      margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }

    .b {
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      display: flex;
    }

    .b:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .c {
      flex: 1;
    }
 
.wrapper:hover .b:not(:hover) .c{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>five</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>six</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>un</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>deux</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>trois</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>quatre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>cinq</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>six</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect! Didn't know about the :(not):hover - thanks.

Comment: Got stuck instantly after implementing this: if I want to change one of the <p> to <a> instead - how can I include links in this?

Comment: ```css
.wrapper:hover .b:not(:hover) a{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: links have precedence for color, so you need to style them directly or instead of putting the tag `a` you can assign them a class and use instead of the `.c` or `a` like in the previous comment